# How do i get a horizontal violin plot or boxplot? (default is vertical in hvplot holoviews)

Tags: python, hvplot, holoviz

Hvplot plots default a vertical violinplot or boxplot. See example below.
How do I get this to be a horizontal plot? So basically I would like to rotate this plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=[100, 2]), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
plot_hvplot = df.hvplot(kind='box')
```

[image: vertical boxplot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding argument **invert=True**, like this:

```
plot_hvplot = df.hvplot(kind='box', invert=True)
```

or by using method **.opts(invert_axes=True)**:

```
plot_hvplot = df.hvplot(kind='box').opts(invert_axes=True)
```

[image]